# What is the best way to run multiple subprocesses via fork()?

Tags: python, linux

A python script need to spawn multiple sub-processes via fork(). All of those child processes  should run simultaneously and the parent process should be waiting for all of them to finish. Having an ability to set some timeout on a "slow" child would be nice.
The parent process goes on processing the rest of the script after all kids are collected.

What is the best way to work it out? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple example:

```
import os
children = []
for job in jobs:
    child = os.fork()
    if child:
        children.append(child)
    else:
        pass  # really should exec the job
for child in children:
    os.waitpid(child, 0)
```

Timing out a slow child is a little more work; you can use `wait` instead of `waitpid`, and cull the returned values from the list of children, instead of waiting on each one in turn (as here).  If you set up an `alarm` with a `SIGALRM` handler, you can terminate the waiting after a specified delay.  This is all standard UNIX stuff, not Python-specific...

Comment: should the child process exit after execution?

Comment: @zuo Child process should `exec` (replacing it with the child to be run) or `_exit`.

Answer (score 7):

*Ephemient*: each child in your code will stay in the for loop after his job ends. He will fork again and again. Moreover, the children that start when children[] is not empty will try to wait for some of their brothers at the end of the loop. Eventually someone will crash. This is a workaround:

```
import os, time

def doTheJob(job):
    for i in xrange(10):
        print job, i
        time.sleep(0.01*ord(os.urandom(1)))
        # random.random() would be the same for each process

jobs = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
imTheFather = True
children = []

for job in jobs:
    child = os.fork()
    if child:
        children.append(child)
    else:
        imTheFather = False
        doTheJob(job)
        break

# in the meanwhile 
# ps aux|grep python|grep -v grep|wc -l == 11 == 10 children + the father

if imTheFather:
    for child in children:
        os.waitpid(child, 0)
```

Comment: As the comment in my source code says, it is necessary to replace "pass" with "exec(job) or similar".  If that is done, everything works as expected.  Also, you'd be better off using os.exit() instead of setting imTheFather.

Comment: @ephemient But why `os._exit()` is better?

Comment: @AloisMahdal use to exit the forked child process http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit

Answer (score 1):

The traditional, UNIX-y way to communicate with sub-processes is to open pipes to their standard input/output, and use the `select()` system call to multiplex the communications in the parent process (available in Python via... the `select` module).

If you need to kill a slow-running child process, you can just save its process ID (returned by the `os.fork()` call) and then use `os.kill()` to kill it when not needed anymore.  Of course, it would probably be cleaner to be able to communicate with the child process explicitly and *tell it* to shut itself down.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in perl a time or two.  Learning python and wanted to replicate the function.   A scheduler for an unknown number of forked tasks must keep track of running tasks, ended tasks, and return codes.  This code includes the code for the SIGCHLD handler, the parent task, and a simple child task.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal, traceback
import os, subprocess
import time
#
#   sigchild handler for reaping dead children
#
def handler(signum, frame):
#
#   report stat of child tasks  
    print(children)
#
#   use waitpid to collect the dead task pid and status
    pid, stat = os.waitpid(-1, 0)
    term=(pid,stat)
    print('Reaped: pid=%d stat=%d\n' % term)
#
#   add pid and return code to dead kids list for post processing
    ripkids.append(term)
    print(ripkids)
    print('\n')
#
#   update children to remove pid just reaped
    index = children.index(pid)
    children.pop(index)
    print(children)   
    print('\n')

# Set the signal handler 
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, handler)

def child():
   print('\nA new child ',  os.getpid())
   print('\n')
   time.sleep(15)
   os._exit(0)  

def parent():
#
# lists for started and dead children
   global children
   children = []
   global ripkids
   ripkids = []

   while True:
      newpid = os.fork()
      if newpid == 0:
         child()
      else:
         pidx = (os.getpid(), newpid)
         children = children+[newpid]
         print("parent: %d, child: %d\n" % pidx)
         print(children)
         print('\n')
      reply = input("q for quit / c for new fork")
      if reply == 'c': 
          continue
      else:
          break

parent()
```